# Can not convert varchar to Date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with dates as a varchar type and the resulted date output (Begin_date) is in the '20130630' format.
I need to convert the begin date output as a date. It doesn't matter what date format as long as it is a date.

I have tried these but none seems to work. I get the ORA-01843 not a valid month error.

```
to_date(aa.Begin_date, 'yyyymmdd')
to_char(to_date(aa.Begin_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mm-yy') 
to_char(to_date(aa.Begin_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-MON-yy')
```

2) Additionally , some begin dates have this format 20030000. Essentially meaning we only know the year. I need to have a output that input a January 1  and year (doesn't matter format).

```
Case when aa.begin_date between '1900' and '2030' 
   then to_date('0101'+aa.begin_date,'YYYYMMDD')
```

I tried a like statement

```
case when aa.begin_date like '%0000' 
   then to_date('0101'+aa.begin_date,'YYYYMMDD') 
end as tes
```

Comment: The ORA-01843 message means your table contains some values that cannot be converted to valid dates. This is the danger of not using the appropriate data type to store data.

Comment: ... and, due to what @APC has said, that process might take time and (a lot of) effort, doing everything in baby-steps as you'll have to filter out invalid values. Who prevents you from entering 'AB42FF73' into that VARHCAR2 column? It is a perfectly valid *string*, but you can't convert it to DATE.  You know how it goes ... garbage in, garbage out. Switch to DATE datatype.

Comment: If `to_date(aa.Begin_date, 'yyyymmdd')` is telling you that the `mm` part is not a valid month, then `to_char(to_date(aa.Begin_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-mm-yy')` is obviously not going to improve things. As for *It doesn't matter what date format as long as it is a date*: the format of the source data is everything. The target `date` column has no format.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
with test_data as
( select '20130630' begin_date from dual 
  union
   select '20030000' begin_date from dual 
)
select 
case when test_data.begin_date like '%0000' then
    to_date(substr(begin_date,1,4)||'0101','YYYYMMDD') 
    else to_date(begin_date,'YYYYMMDD') end my_date
from test_data
```

But best thing is to correct your data model to use real DATE type. Storing dates as a string is a bad design.

Comment: Not only is it a questionable design choice, it also takes more memory/disk to store date-as-string (8 characters) than it does to store date-as-DATE (7 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT to_date('20130630','YYYYMMDD') FROM dual
```

Comment: you just need to put in proper dates as it is a varchar type

Comment: Thank you all. We will try to cleanup the original data.